# Run time error '1004', Unable to set the Hidden property of the range class

Tags: excel, vba

The code below work well if i don't use the protected sheet. It appears above error when i selected protected sheet. i don't know what happened. Can anyone advise?

```
Sub Hide_Unhide()

If Range("A4").Value = "Yes" Then
Rows("4:4").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
Rows("4:4").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If

If Range("A5").Value = "Yes" Then
Rows("5:5").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Else
Rows("5:5").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
End sub
```

Comment: Unprotect first, then hide, then re-protect.

Comment: Is there any way to protect it but still can run the macro? I want to protect sheet but macro still can work when i click on the command button. Now the command button does not work when i protect sheet.

Comment: `Rows("4:4").EntireRow.Hidden = (Range("A4").Value = "Yes")` is more concise

Comment: Thank you Tim Williams. Does it cause the error i am having?

Comment: No but @BigBen already gave you the answer to that - unprotect the sheet before hding/unhiding the rows.

Comment: I think my question was that how can i protect sheet while the hide/unhide macro is still working. Now, i have trouble to generate the macro when i protect sheet. And i need to fix it before letting people to use it while don't touch my marco